# Spring upgrade from 3.1.1.RELEASE TO 3.2.0.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

im trying to upgrade my spirng verison from 3.1.1.RELEASE TO 3.2.0.RELEASE

here below are my pom.xml and spring-security.xml

pom.xml->

```
  <properties>
     <java.version>1.8</java.version>
     <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

 <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
<!--                <exclusion>-->
<!--                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>-->
<!--                    <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>-->
<!--                </exclusion>-->
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
          
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
           
        </dependency>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
           
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0.RELEASE</version>
           
        </dependency>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
           
        </dependency>

           <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
           
        </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.RELEASE</version>
           
        </dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

here is spring.security.xml ->

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"              xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"              xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd                                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">      <security:http authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"                    create-session="never">         <security:form-login authentication-failure-url="/start" login-page="/start" />         <security:logout />     </security:http>      <security:global-method-security authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"                                      pre-post-annotations="enabled" /> </beans:beans>  im getting this following error while trying to run the application  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [D:\BMG\Project\MSOL\bmg-songs-msol\target\msol-2.1.1\WEB-INF\classes\com\bmg\repository\elastic\crud\ESCrudRepository.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:281) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:123) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:218) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]   at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:139) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null   at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52) ~[spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]  at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80) ~[spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]     at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101) ~[spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:257) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]   ... 59 common frames omitted
```

im trying to upgrade my spring version from 3.1.1.RELEASE TO 3.2.0.RELEASE im getting the following exceptions while building also im getting some exceptions when i try to build it skippin tests it build properly while running its giving these exceptions

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [D:\BMG\Project\MSOL\bmg-songs-msol\target\msol-2.1.1\WEB-INF\classes\com\hub\repository\hubcrd\hubsim\HubRepository.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:281) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:242) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:123) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:218) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:139) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]



Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:52) ~[spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80) ~[spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101) ~[spring-core-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:257) ~[spring-context-3.2.0.RELEASE.jar:3.2.0.RELEASE]
    ... 59 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Spring 3.2 does not support Java 1.8. Are you sure that you want to upgrade to a Spring version that was released more than a decade ago (in December 2012)?

Comment: @ThomasKläger i wanted to update it to highest version of 3.2.X so was going step by step

Comment: When you want to use Spring 3.2 (even the highest version of Spring 3.2) you must use Java 1.7 (not Java 1.8 or any later version like Java 17). If you want to use Java 1.8 you must upgrade to at least Spring 4.0. If you want to do it in steps then you need to install Java 1.7 for the step from Spring 3.1 to Spring 3.2.